# How to Restrict Access Parse.com API to One Only Session Token (One Device) per Time?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, session, parse-platform, pfuser

I'm developing an App that use Parse.com as a Backend :

- I Can Login from any device with the same PFUser in the same time
- I Can Change anything in One device and see the change immediately in the other device

In Small words, Everything works perfectly !

**MY GOALS**

1) Is it possible to Restrict the Login to Only 1 device Per Time ?

2) If Yes, How can i disconnect the Previous device when the New one login ?

Thanks

Comment: Hey, did you ever find a solution to your question? I am working on a similar  issue in my app.

Comment: I am also looking for the same solution, Can any one worked on this thing ?